# how to Get Most Viewed posts grouped by date?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I want to sort my posts to show most viewed posts grouped by date, so that top viewed posts each day appear then the next then the next.

How to write this query in linq? method based if possible.

Comment: Could you post your code in here?

Comment: it was something as @Thom Smith wrote, but my select was not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int postsPerDay = 5;

var topPostsByDate = Posts
    .GroupBy(post => post.Date)
    .Select(grp => new
        {
            Date = grp.Key,
            TopPosts = grp
                .OrderByDescending(post => post.Views)
                .Take(postsPerDay)
                .Select(post => new Post(post))
        })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

EDIT: Constructs a new Post object from the data row. Assumes that Post has a constructor accepting a `DataRow`; alter to fit.

Comment: and how to return Posts entities from this query, not anonymous type?

Comment: Edit'd. Now returns `IGrouping<DateTime, Post>`.